# Set variable to a new value if a specific class is present in LESS

Tags: css, if-statement, less

It is easy to explain what I want using an example.

I want to achieve something like

```
.someClass {
   @aVariable: 100px;
   /*
   if(along with .someClass .anotherClass is present) {
      @aVariable = 200px;
   }
   */
   /*@aVariable is used here */
}
```

The point is to set `@aVariable` depending on the another class presence.

I saw [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358664/check-if-parent-has-class-using-less) answer, but it did not work out for me.

Comment: It would be better if you'd describe you actual goal and not *how you think you''ll achieve* it (e.g. it's really an XY-Problem). The question is *why* you need that variable and *how* you're going to use it. (The way you want it above is simply impossible because neither variables nor class definitions work like that in Less).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.someClass {
   @aVariable: 100px;

   /*@aVariable should be used here */

   &.anotherClass {
       @aVariable: 200px;

    /*2nd @aVariable should be used here. this will overide above css*/
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to do that so that to avoid repeating what is written outside of `.anotherClass` for a new `@aVariable` value. But your solution does not help to achieve this, but still thanks.